# Python: IF sentence inside bar plot

Tags: python, if-statement, plot, bar-chart

It might sound strange, but I need to have IF sentence inside bar plot line.
My part of code:

```
for col in columns[2:32:2]:
    plt.bar([p + width*n for p in pos], df[col], width, color=colors[n], hatch='x')
```

I have DataFrame df. I need to plot every second value of its column in grouped bars (grouped according to row) and every other second of that contains a value 0 or 1. According to that 0 or 1 value I need to have bar hatched or not. I was trying to insert IF sentence inside plt.bar(), but I was not successful.

Any ideas how to do it? If it is possible at all

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if I understood it correctly but you can access the second element (for each row and for every column) as

```
for col in columns[2:32:2]:
     plt.bar([p + width*n for p in pos], df[col[:,1]], width, color=colors[n], hatch='x')
```

so instead of having IF statement, you can try indexing of `col` that suits you.